# Colour graph beetwen point and lyne

Tags: r, graph, colors

I have this graph, with different colour based on the column 4 of the data frame df_ricos.

[image]

the code for the graph  is:
 `>plot(df_ricos[,1],df_ricos[,3],col=df_ricos[,4])`

Why if a change the type of the graph from point to lines the result is all black?

Comment: please post df_ricos. you can do this by typing `dput(df_ricos)` and pasting the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, I think, because you have a data frame, not a time series. You could format your data.frame as time series and plot, as you have one series coloring part of the line would need more work.
One approach, without time series, would be sorting according to time column and plot whit `type="b"`:

```
df_ricos2=df_ricos[order(df_ricos[,1]),]
plot(df_ricos2[,1],df_ricos2[,3],col=df_ricos2[,4],type="b")
```

Comment: You are rigth, the problem is that is not a time series. If i want to change the color the solution is create two time series and after plot them with       > lines (....).    Thank you!

Comment: The second problem is that my ts for each color is not continuative!!